# How to store the coordinates of a polygon in php MySQL fetched from Google Map

Tags: php, mysqli, spatial

```
<?php $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "users";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
//    SET @g = 'POLYGON($_POST[coords])';
$coords = $_POST['coords'];
//$stmt = "INSERT INTO polygon_data (polygon_values) VALUES (PolygonFromText('POLYGON((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))'))";
$stmt = "INSERT INTO polygon_data (polygon_values) VALUES (PolygonFromText('$coords'))";
if ($mysqli->query($stmt) === TRUE) {
    echo "feedback sucessfully submitted";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $stmt  . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

When I inserted static values like in commented line, data stored in MySql successfully and also my attribute `pollygon_values` in mysql is of Polygon DataType.

Comment: Try print_r $coords; and check what is stored in the variable

Comment: Dear Dharman                                                                                                   The coordinates of polygon that i received from Google Maps are not correct e.g.i receive the coordinates of three point polygon (63.27444617179118,59.28299672851564,64.36014718275916,77.56424672851564,58.403184272819026,74.04862172851564) and from here we can see that the first and last points of coordinates are not same. Means receive incorrect data and that's why MySQL store NULL instead of wrong values.Why all of this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine, but we need to take care in mind that the first thing is that **the data type that you select on MySQL is Geometry or Polygon** and the second thing you **should check either the values of coordinates of Polygon that you get from Google Maps are accurate** means their latitudes and longitudes values are right and also exists and that was mine problem, i was not getting right coordinates of Polygon drawn on Google Map.